# How to use the accessibilty service to detect changes in a TextView

Tags: android

I'm trying to learn how works the accesibility service. I have done a basic class to detect the Accessibility Service and it works, but I have a question.

Is possible to detect some change in a TextView that can change in the layout, and how can I do it???

These are some of the events that I use:

```
        case AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_NOTIFICATION_STATE_CHANGED:
        case AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_CLICKED:
        case AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_FOCUSED:
        case AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_LONG_CLICKED:
        case AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_SELECTED:
        case AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_WINDOW_STATE_CHANGED:
        case AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_WINDOWS_CHANGED:
        case AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_WINDOW_CONTENT_CHANGED:
        case AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_TEXT_CHANGED:
        case AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_SCROLLED:
```

Thanks in advance